# Null Row Cell in GridView with 'Date' type

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've used rowdatabind code in gridview for expired date alert by colored row those dates already have expired. My table's column ExpDate type is "date". its works well but now the problem is- when any row cell become null, its given error. my gridviewrowDatabound code is-

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[8].Text);
        if (date < DateTime.Now)
        {
            GridView1.Rows[i].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            GridView1.Rows[i].Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            GridView1.Rows[i].Visible = false;
        }
    }


}
```

Showing error : "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime" , for code line- " DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[8].Text);" 
now what can i do. anyone can give me an idea, please!!

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: Put a debugger and verify what value you are getting for `e.Row.Cells[3].Text` when exception occured

Comment: when i click this Edit link, given this type of error. after debug this line showing error this line[previous commnent] @irvgk

Comment: share edit command code as well

Comment: In the `OnRowEditing` event handler, you must set the `EditIndex` and then rebind the data to the GridView. Please have a look at my answer in the following post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36827111/asp-net-gridview-how-to-edit-and-delete-data-records/36828018#36828018.

Comment: i've tried but not worked @ConnorsFan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you do the "painting" work in client-side?

I use this code for that (put it in the aspx file):

```
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function pageLoad() {
        $('#MainContent_gridView td').each(function () {

            //YOUR VALIDATION
            if ($(this).html() == "STATUS 1") {
                $(this).attr("class", "text-info");
            }

            if ($(this).html() == "STATUS 2") {
                $(this).attr("class", "text-error");
            }

            if ($(this).html() == "STATUS 3") {
                $(this).attr("class", "text-success");
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Be carefull with the "pageLoad" method, if you are not using "pageLoad" in your Master Page don't worry.
I prefer to do the "painting" work client-side because I don't like going to the server just for something I can do client-side

Comment: i cant understand this jS code. My problem is null value in the "ExpDate" column cell with type "date".

Comment: Post the design code of the GridView (<asp:GridView....), maybe it need a change. I also want to ask: it's correct that you receive a null value? or it actually has a value but it throws "null"?