# GridView Editing OnRowDataBound Field With ReadIOnly="false" Has No Value

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView.
It has many fields on it.
There is only one field in a row that I want to be able to edit called 'Units'.
'Units' is the only field with `ReadOnly="true"` (all the rest are `ReadOnly="false"`);

I am also using an `OnRowDataBound` 
In the `OnRowDataBound` I perform some calculations that involve the value
of 'Unit' to populate some templatefield / itemtemplate values (Unbound Columns).

My problem is when I click the 'Edit' button on a row:
1.) `OnRowEdit()` is called which re-creates the `SelectCommand` if required.
    If I do not do this the contents of the GridViewPackaging disappears.
2.) The `OnRowdataBound()` will be called due to the `GridViewPackaging.DataBind()`.
3.) In the `OnRowDataBound()` the value for 'Units' (`Cells[8].Text`) is an empty
    string.

Why is this so?

If I set 'Units' to `ReadOnly="false"` then the value for Units (`Cells[8].text`)
is now there within the `OnRowdataBind()`.

```
private void GridViewPackagingSelectStatement()
{System.String SelectStatment;

 // Giant SQL Multiple table INNER JOIN, WHERE removed for readability.
 this.SqlDataSourcePackaging.SelectCommand=SelectStatment;

 }

protected void GridViewPackaging_OnRowEdit(object sender,GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
 // If I Do Not Do This Then My GridView Will Not be Populated (i.e. it Will Be Empty).
 this.GridViewPackagingSelectStatement();
 this.GridViewPackaging.EditIndex=e.NewEditIndex; 
 }

protected void GridViewPackaging_UnboundColumns(object sender,GridViewRowEventArgs e)
 {System.Int32 UsageIndex=0;
  System.Int32 CurrentUnits=0;
  System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlMoney CostPerUnit=0;

  if(e.Row.RowType==DataControlRowType.DataRow) 
  {
   // Removed Code For readability

   // e.Row.Cells[8] Is 'Units'
   // This Code Structure Is For Debugging
   if((e.Row.RowState&DataControlRowState.Edit)!=DataControlRowState.Edit)
   {
    if(e.Row.RowIndex==1) // For Debugging, For Breakpoint On Next Line
    {
     // Cells[8] Always Has The Correct Value When I Am Not Editing the Row
     CurrentUnits=Convert.ToInt32(e.Row.Cells[8].Text);
     }

    CurrentUnits=Convert.ToInt32(e.Row.Cells[8].Text);
    }
   else 
   {
    if(e.Row.RowIndex==1) //For Debugging, For Breakpoint On Next Line
    {
     // When Editing Length Is Always 0, .Text=""! Why Is This So?
     // If I Set Unit (Which Is Row[8]) To ReadOnly="false" Then The
     // Value Is There But I Will Not be Able To Edit It. Huh?
     if(e.Row.Cells[8].Text.Length!=0)
     {
      CurrentUnits=Convert.ToInt32(e.Row.Cells[8].Text);
      }
     }
    }

   // Removed Code For readability   
  }
```

Thanks.

Comment: You can have a look at my answer to the following post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36827111/asp-net-gridview-how-to-edit-and-delete-data-records/36828018#36828018. You will see that, in `OnRowEdit`, you must first set the `EditIndex` and then rebind the data (at least calling `GridViewPackaging.DataBind()`).

Comment: Sorry but I am having problems editing a comment.

Comment: Sorry. I have never used StackOverflow before. Though it does not make sense to me I set .EditIndex before GridViewPackagingSelectStatement() in OnRowEdit. I added .DataBind() after .SelectCommand= in GridViewPackagingSelectStatement(). (It binds twice now as I suspected). Nothing has changed, Units still has no length when I am in edit mode.