# GridView RowIndex is 0

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

I have a GridView on my page and I click on `Edit`, it displays my editable text box but when I edit the value and press `Update` it errors:

The error suggests that `GridView2.DataKeys` is `null`.

I adding some extra debugging by:

`int test = e.RowIndex`

and this gives me a value of `0`

My code is below:

Can you suggest why im getting:

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative
>   and less than the size of the collection.

```
protected void GridView2_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)

{
    int DataKeyValue = Convert.ToInt32(GridView2.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)GridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    Label lblID = (Label)row.FindControl("lblID");

    TextBox GVtxtNextStep = (TextBox)row.Cells[0].Controls[0];

    GridView2.EditIndex = -1;

    cobj.SupportRef1 = txtSupportRef.Text;
    cobj.NextStep1 = txtNextStep.Text;


    bobj.MicroTicketUpdate(cobj);

    GridView2.DataBind();

}
```

Comment: You can check the following post to see if something in your procedure is incorrect: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36827111/asp-net-gridview-how-to-edit-and-delete-data-records/36828018#36828018.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the `DataKeyNames` property on your GridView control to the relevant ID property e.g. `<asp:GridView DataKeyNames="PersonID"`...

**EDIT**

Below is a complete example which will return a valid primary key value in the `DataKeyValue` variable.You can copy this example, as is, into a new web page in your web application and test it to see how it works and how the data get's bound and I hope by looking at this example you can figure out the changes you should make to your code to get it working:

**.ASPX:**

```
<asp:GridView 
    DataKeyNames="ID" 
    ID="GridView1" 
    runat="server" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
    AutoGenerateEditButton="True" 
    OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing" 
    OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating" OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CreditRequest" HeaderText="Credit Request" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

**Code behind:**

```
 public class PersonT
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string CreditRequest { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class aaaa_GridViewRowUpdating : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                this.BindData();
            }
        }

        private void BindData()
        {
            var p1 = new PersonT() { ID = 10, Name = "Person 1", CreditRequest = "Credit Request 1" };
            var p2 = new PersonT() { ID = 20, Name = "Person 2", CreditRequest = "Credit Request 2" };

            var list = new List<PersonT> { p1, p2 };
            GridView1.DataSource = list;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }

        protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
        {
            GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
            BindData();
        }

        protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
            int index = e.RowIndex;
            int DataKeyValue = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[index].Value.ToString());
        }

        protected void GridView1_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
        {
            GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
            BindData();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is that the primary key in my DB table?

Comment: I mean the fields in my datasource?

Comment: Yes exactly.It might be called ID or PersonID e.t.c

Comment: I added that but my rowIndex is still 0. I think its because when i am in edit mode, i run `LoadAllTicketUpdates(txtSupportRef.Text);` which gets rid of the index due to a databind of the GridView. So i guess i need figure out how to bind my GridView2 when in edit mode. Ahh

Comment: So int DataKeyValue is equal to 0 in the RowUpdating event?And you want it to contain the primary key?Do i understand right?

Comment: Edit your question and post the .aspx markup for your gridview as well as the Edit event of the gridview

Answer (score 0):

if yo click outside of the rows but on the data view the row index which is returned is -1. You have to check if this occurs and break out of the code if it does eg.

```
if (e.RowIndex<0&&e.RowIndex>=gridiew.Rows.Count)//have to account for the blan row
return;
```

Comment: My issue is that i DO have a row but its showing up in the index as `0`